# Customizing data tips in editor - Deal with structs

Tags: matlab

This question is linked to that Q&A I posted around 1 year ago : [Customizing data tips in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828551/customizing-data-tips-in-editor/33829235#33829235)

The goal was to customize the datatips that are shown when you hover on a variable in editor.

The solutions presented there work well for standard variables. As of today I'm starting to work with structures in order to get things cleaner, but the hack of `datatipinfo.m` doesn't work anymore.

Here is what happens :

[image]

As you can see, only the parent structure gets a datatip on hover.

What I would want to do, (according to excaza's answer to my last question which allows to get rid of external dependencies) :

- I create a structure with the same names as my variables which contains the descriptions

For this example that would be along the line of `DATASTRINGS.DATA_GEOMETRIE.GLOBAL.Nsats='description'`

- Now I'd like to hack the `datatipinfo` function so that when I hover on a variable, instead of showing a description of the parent structure, it would fetch the whole name and show the linked description.

If you take a look at the `datatipinfo.m` code (Type `edit datatipinfo` in command window), there is a part to deal with structures :

```
function datatipinfo(val)

% Some stuff

if isstruct(val)
        % disp the result of display, without the equal sign and
        % with the correct variable name.
        displayStr = evalcWithHotlinksOff('display(val)');
        pat = '\s*val\s*=\s*([^\n]*)\n+';
        rep = [name, ': $1\n'];
        if isscalar(val) && numel(fieldnames(val)) > 0
            pat = '\s*val\s*=\s*\n+';
            rep = [name, ':\n'];
        end
        disp(regexprep(displayStr, pat, rep, 'once'));
    elseif isempty(val)
        callDisp('sizeType');

    else

% Some other stuff

end
```

But I can't quite get what's going on there..

Any ideas?

---

### EDIT :

I can get the custom datatip to work but only for the parent struct, as shown below :

[image]

I modified the code as follow to add the comment when `val` is a struct

```
if isstruct(val)
        % disp the result of display, without the equal sign and
        % with the correct variable name.
        displayStr = evalcWithHotlinksOff('display(val)');
        if NameFound

           disp(Comment); 

        end


        % Rest of function

    elseif isempty(val)

        %

    else

end
```

But I'm having a hard time to get MATLAB to fire the `datatipinfo` for the structure fields. It comes from the fact that MATLAB don't recognize the fields of a struct as variables.